# If a Chrome Extension is published as private to my company's domain, is it still subject to the single-purpose policy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that will be private to my company's domain (registered under a Google For Business account). But I've read that google maintains a strict single-purpose policy as outlined in their [Extensions Quality Guidelines FAQ](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/single_purpose) and I am doubtful if the tool I'm building will comply with Google's single-purpose policy.

It's understandable why Google would want to ensure quality on public extensions by enforcing these rules, but they weren't clear on its applicability to private extensions.

Can anyone state definitively, whether or not this policy applies to privately published extensions?

---

**UPDATE - 1/4/2017**

Got an official response from the **Chrome Web Store Developer Support** team and I quote:

> In regards to your question, the answer is YES, it is still subject to the single-purpose policy even for private domain items. Please refer to [Chromium Blog](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/12/keeping-chrome-extensions-simple.html) for more information.

So it appears even private domains have to abide by the single-purpose policy.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ you linked states that if you don't follow the guidelines, what will happen is

> your extension will not be permitted in the Chrome Web Store

or,

> your extension may be removed from the Chrome Web Store

As you must publish your extension to the Chrome Web Store (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/hosting_changes)), these guidelines can technically be applied.

To get a definitive answer,

> you can email chromewebstore-policy@google.com with your extension ID, and we’ll take a look and try to provide feedback within a week.

If you really want to get around this, you will have to research ways to distribute your extension outside of the store. [Here](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453) is an example for enterprise.

Comment: Sent them an email before posting the original question, but I'm told they take a while to respond so I decided to present the issue here as well. I read that bit about Force installing but for a company with a large staff  that's something I'd prefer to avoid since it would mean manually installing the extension for each member of staff.

Comment: @DimuDesigns yes this is a bit of an iffy situation, please let us know what they reply

Comment: The folks from Chrome Web Store Dev Support responded. I've updated my initial post to reflect the info they provided.